# Aplicar number_format em variável

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte:

```
$_POST['stock_unity_push'] = "R$ 0,25";
$stock_unity_push = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("R$ ", "", $_POST['stock_unity_push']));
```

Eu preciso transformar este resultado em 0.25. Porém, se eu aplicar dessa forma:

```
$stock_unity_push = number_format((float)$stock_unity_push, 2, '.', ',');
```

Meu resultado é 0.00, como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente, o problema é que vc está convertendo a *string* `"0,25"` em *float*:

```
$foo = "R$ 0,25";
$stock_unity_push = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("R$ ", "", $foo));
var_dump($stock_unity_push); // string(4) "0,25"
echo '<br/>';
$foo = (float) $stock_unity_push;
var_dump($foo); // float (0)
$stock_unity_push = number_format($foo, 2, '.', ',');
```

**Solução**: Substituir a vírgula por ponto:

```
$foo = "R$ 0,25";
$stock_unity_push = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("R$ ", "", $foo));
var_dump($stock_unity_push); // string(4) "0,25"
// Solução:
$stock_unity_push = str_replace(',', '.', $stock_unity_push); // "0,25" vira "0.25"
echo '<br/>';
$foo = (float) $stock_unity_push;
var_dump($foo); // float (0)
$stock_unity_push = number_format($foo, 2, '.', ',');
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($stock_unity_push); // string(4) "0.25"
```